# Apache/Flask: app hangs at certain points

Tags: apache-http-server, python, flask

I've got a Flask app served by Apache that hangs at certain points when answering a request from a client. This happens at various points in the code, though it appears to be deterministic when it happens -- say it happens at line `n`, but when I comment out that line (or do things another way) it then hangs at line `m` (with `m>n`). These points in the code do not do anything crazy that's particularly memory or CPU-intensive. I observe hardware consumption with `htop` and everything looks very comfortable there.

I do not get any error or warning, it just freezes, then I get a timeout.

I know this is a very vague description of the problem but I can't see what other specifics would be helpful. Any help is greatly appreciated though!

Software:
httpd 2.4.6 on RHEL 3.10.0, with Python 3.6.8, Flask 1.1.1.